# Access the first value from the first row of a Joomla query result

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5, resultset

I tried to extract a specific data in a table but my code does not work:

```
$db =& JFactory::getDBO(); 
$query = "SELECT * FROM #_contact_details WHERE user_id = 43;";
$db->setQuery($query);
$results = $db->loadObjectList();
$results = $results["name"];
```

`$results` does not give anything.

Answer (score 0):

$results is not giving anything because `loadObjectList()` returns array of object so the result(structure) would be for one row similar to this-

print_r($results)

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => "test"
        )
)
```

so you can read data like this `$results = $results[0]->name;`

You can [read here](http://docs.joomla.org/Accessing_the_database_using_JDatabase/1.5)

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

The `$result` is an array of `stdClass Object`. If you want to access the value You've to use:

```
$results = $results[0]->name;
```

Hope this helps!